# How do I not return the graph when querying?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there anything in cypher that will not draw the graph? My computer is slowing down to a crawl because of how big the database is and how many nodes and relationships are being returned.
I want just the Tables or Text.

Answer (score 0):

You mean in the browser ? When you call the same query from an application it will not visualize (obviously, your application will have to handle what you asked for however) but that is the default behaviour for the browser. Now, if you just want properties in a tabular format, specify them like that, for example :

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n.name
```

instead of

```
MATCH (n) RETURN n
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Additionally you can `RETURN properties(n)` to return the properties map instead of the node itself.